# app crashing after creating search interface

Tags: android, android-search

I am new to android and i am following [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) tutorial for creating a search interface.

my Searchable Configuration xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint ="@string/search_hint"
    >
</searchable>
```

mainactivity file content:

```
package com.searchingapp.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        **EDIT**
        EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                onSearchRequested();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

searchActivity file content:

```
package com.searchingapp.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Searchactivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchactivity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if ( Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals( intent.getAction() ) )
        {
            String search_query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            TextView search_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            search_text.setText(search_query);
        }

    }

}
```

And finally the mainfest file **i think the problem is in this file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.searchingapp.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.searchingapp.android.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".Searchactivity" />

           ________________________/\_______________
                                  here

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Searchactivity" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT** :

logcat output :

```
06-16 01:16:33.778: D/AndroidRuntime(1224): Shutting down VM
06-16 01:16:33.778: W/dalvikvm(1224): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xadac0ba8)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224): Process: com.searchingapp.android, PID: 1224
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.searchingapp.android/com.searchingapp.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at com.searchingapp.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-16 01:16:33.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1224):     ... 11 more
06-16 01:16:50.848: I/Process(1224): Sending signal. PID: 1224 SIG: 9
```

NEW catlog output :

```
06-16 01:31:01.168: D/AndroidRuntime(1459): Shutting down VM
06-16 01:31:01.168: W/dalvikvm(1459): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xadac0ba8)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): Process: com.searchingapp.android, PID: 1459
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.searchingapp.android/com.searchingapp.android.Searchactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.searchingapp.android.Searchactivity.onCreate(Searchactivity.java:23)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-16 01:31:01.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     ... 11 more
```

can anyone tell me where i am doing the stupid thing.

Comment: Where is Logcat output?

Comment: @LittleSuzy i added logcat output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

You are casting an edittext to button.

Change that according to cast it to edittext, or use button in xml.

Comment: it crashed again check new logcat

Comment: @user3742981 what s line Searchactivity.java:23?

Comment: search_text.setText(search_query);

Comment: So either search_text or search_query is null. Did you debug what;s null? @user3742981

Comment: @user3742981 Make sure you are using correct textview from xml, `textView1` and make sure you are using correct reference to fetch data `search_query` which is `SearchManager.QUERY`

Comment: actually i don't know how to do debug!!

Comment: @user3742981 what does `System.out.println("textview: "+search_text);` and `System.out.println("searchQuery: "+search_query);` give in logcat? Put these two lines just before `search_text.setText(search_query);` and tell me what you get

Comment: `06-16 02:00:32.310: I/System.out(991): textview: null`
`06-16 02:00:32.310: I/System.out(991): searchQuery: ok`

Comment: @user3742981 Textview is null. Please show xml file `activity_searchactivity` in your question

Comment: it worked i forget to add textview in search activity my mistake and thanks a ton for your help :)

Comment: and at last one more question is there a way to create search interface like google search app without changing activity or not changing the text box

Comment: And @user3742981 learn to debug application as soon as possible. It will come in handy for sure. :) When you deal with big applications, it won't be good to use `sysout` for so many lines :)

Comment: @user3742981 That I don't know, as I didn't work on such thing. sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing stupid thing here. ;)

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Use

`Theme.AppCompat` theme because `Searchactivity extends ActionBarActivity`

Solution # 2:

As you need fullscreen Activity Then extending from `ActionBarActivity` Extend your `Searchactivity` from `Activity`

Comment: i tested your solution the problem is not there hence thank you.

Comment: where is Logcat output?

Comment: Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Comment: it crashed again check new logcat